# In Excel VBA, create a group without using Application Selection

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, to create a group of rows I have seen many articles which use `Range.Select` followed by `Selection.Group`. However, that convulses the UI, as the process of setting Selection actually sets Excel's visible selection.  (I guess Selection is actually Application.Selection?)

There must surely be a way to set a group without using Selection?  Is there perhaps a sheet groups property to which one can add rows? Or perhaps the real question is how to create a Selection without using the visible Selection?

Comment: What do you mean? To Group the rows in range `A1:A3` for instance you can just do `Range("A1:A3").Rows.Group`.

Comment: Almost always (there are always exceptions) if you see something like `x.Select` followed by `Selection.y`, it can be combined as `x.y`.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks for the prod, I'll give this a try. So why do so many existing articles use Selection? Hmmm.

Comment: @gwideman that's a good question, because generally it's best practice to [avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). A guess is because if you use the macro recorder to record some VBA, it's riddled with the use

Comment: @BruceWayne and YowE3K: Well no surprise to you guys I'm sure, but Range("whatever").Rows.Group works great.  By great, I mean it does the job, and it's soooooo much better behavior than using Selection.  Bruce -- feel free to write up an answer and I'll give it the check mark.

Comment: @BruceWayne My theory on the wide usage of `Selection` is that many vba users learn by recording macros, and the UI for excel pretty exclusively relies on users selecting a cell before doing anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `selection.rows.group` with `Range(yourRange).rows.group`
where `yourRange` is either replaced with a literal range or used as a range variable.

Unless you always only work with one excel document at any given moment:
A good practice is to always use `ThisWorkbook.sheets(sheet1.name).Range(yourRange)`:
This applies the code in the same workbook as the code reside in.

If you don't, VBA will default to `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(yourRange)`